# Spring JMS configure JmsListeners dynamically

Tags: java, spring-jms

I want to create JmsListeners dynamically. To do so I have created a `JMSconfig` class as explained in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#jms-annotated-programmatic-registration).

Queues have been defined in an ActiveMQ Artemis server:

```java
public class JMSConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    private static Logger logger = 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSConfig.class);
    

    @Autowired
    JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
    
    @Value("${activemq.broker-url}")
    String brokerUrl; 
    
    @Value("${activemq.user}")
    String brokerUsername; 
    
    @Value("${activemq.password}")
    String brokerPassword;
    
    @Value("${activemq.concurrency}")
    String brokerConcurency;
    
    
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setUser(brokerUsername);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(brokerPassword);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConcurrency(brokerConcurency);
        factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(1);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        
        registrar.setEndpointRegistry(registry);
        List<String> queueList = Arrays.asList("Queue1","Queue2");
        int i = 0;
       
        for (String queueName :queueList) {
            SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
            String endpointId = "myJmsEndpoint-" + i++;
            endpoint.setId(endpointId);
            endpoint.setDestination(queueName);
                  
            endpoint.setMessageListener(message -> {
                Serializable content = ((BackendMessage) message).getContent();
                log.info("***********************************************receivedMessage:" + content);
                logger.info("Receive : {}", content);
            });
            
            registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);          
            log.info("registered the endpoint for queue " + queueName);   
         }
       }
    }
```

I have created another `JmsListener using annotation:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageConsumer {
 
    @JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "jmsFactory", id = "myQueue")
    public void processToDo(BackendMessage message) {
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - Receive message: " + message.getContent());
    }
}
```

In my pom.xml I have the following dependencies :

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>

        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The problem is that the static `JmsListener` defined with the `@JmsListener` annotation works fine. When I send a message to the queue `myQueue` the listener receive the message.

However, dynamic listeners defined in the `JMSConfig` class in the `configureJmsListeners` method don't work. When I send messages to the queue `Queue1` or `Queue2` listeners don't receive the message.

Is there something wrong in the way I declare the dynamic listeners in the `JMSConfig` class?

Comment: The messages are consumed by the jmsListener. The problem seems to be a ClasClastException in the MessageListener  :  Serializable content = ((BackendMessage) message).getContent() . The message received is a javax.jms.Message and not a BackendMessage. However no Exception can be seen in the logs. I see this problem in the debugger

Comment: You should update the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your message listener in a `MessageListenerAdapter`; it will convert the JMS `Message` to your object.